# How do you use PHPUnit with VSCode?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpunit

I've done some PHPUnit tests with Netbeans, but couldn't get the latest version (PHPUnit 8) to work. So I'd like to try it in VSCode.

Any suggestions or links to tutorials on getting them to work together?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you run into an error? Did you try some of the options that came up when you google phpunit and vscode?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a custom task in the `tasks.json` file that should be located in the `.vscode` directory. The custom task can be something like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run tests",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "phpunit",
            "args": ["--stop-on-error"],
            "group": "test",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Read more about it in the documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks